# How to pass id of each item in for loop to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I need to add id of each item to the function of `onchange` event, but the `<select>` tag does not accept expression.

Once user selects a category from the list, the id of the associated item along with value of  should be sent to Ajax to be sent to the back-end.

```
 <c:forEach var="item" items="${Items}">
        .....
       <s:select id="name" 
                 name="name"
                 list="@interfaces.Lists@Category"
                 value="item.category"
                 onchange='changeItemCategory(${item.id},this.value)'
       />
 </c:forEach>
```

It does not accept %{item.id} as well, when I try item.id it sends the request to the function but proid variable's value will be 'undefined'.

```
 <script> 

 function changeItemCategory(proid,cat){
     alert(proid+cat);
     .....
 }

 </script>
```

**Error:**

```
 According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute `onchange` does not accept 
 any expressions.
```

Comment: what is the `id`? is it an int value or a string

Comment: the id is an integer.

Comment: is EL expression not accepting by select tag?  check if you have isELIgnored = true

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar question is updated.

Comment: where exactly are you seeing your error?

Comment: @Derek There is no error, it does not send the value of item.id to the function. When I use OGNL as Dave explained, it does not call the function and , FireBug shows,  changeItemCategory(,this.value) and there is an arrow under comma. The FireBug error is SyntaxError: syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Use OGNL, not JSP EL:

```
onchange='changeItemCategory(%{#item.id}, this.value)'
```

Comment: It does not call the function, FireBug shows,  changeItemCategory(,this.value) and there is an arrow under comma. The FireBug error is SyntaxError: syntax error

Comment: in the page source also, it is like changeItemCategory(,this.value)

Comment: @AlexCartio1 Oh, you're using jstl to iterate, use the s2 iterator instead, sorry.